# How to force open PDF on chrome/FF/IE PHP

Tags: javascript, php, fpdf

```
<?PHP
require("../fpdf/fpdf.php");
include("db.classes.php");
$g = new DB();
$g->connection();

class PDF extends FPDF {

    function header() {
    $this->SetXY(10,0);
    $this->image('../images/homeHeader.png');
    }
    function Footer()
    {
    // Go to 1.5 cm from bottom
    $this->SetY(-15);
    // Select Arial italic 8
    $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
    // Print centered page number
    $this->Cell(0,10,'All Rights Reserved 2014',0,0,'C');
    }   

    function BuildTable($header,$data) {

    //Colors, line width and bold font

    $this->SetFillColor(255,0,0);

    $this->SetTextColor(255);

    $this->SetDrawColor(128,0,0);

    $this->SetLineWidth(.3);

    $this->SetFont('','B');

    //Header

    // make an array for the column widths

    $w=array(80,25,35,50,35,110);

    // send the headers to the PDF document

    for($i=0;$i<count($header);$i++)

    $this->Cell($w[$i],7,$header[$i],1,0,'C',1);

    $this->Ln();

    //Color and font restoration

    $this->SetFillColor(175);

    $this->SetTextColor(0);

    $this->SetFont('');



    //now spool out the data from the $data array

    $fill=true; // used to alternate row color backgrounds

    foreach($data as $row)

    {

    // set colors to show a URL style link

    $this->Cell($w[0],6,$row[0],'LR',0,'L',$fill);

    // restore normal color settings

    $this->SetTextColor(0);

    $this->SetFont('');

    $this->Cell($w[1],6,$row[1],'LR',0,'C',$fill);
    $this->Cell($w[2],6,$row[2],'LR',0,'C',$fill);
    $this->Cell($w[3],6,$row[3],'LR',0,'C',$fill);
    $this->Cell($w[4],6,$row[4],'LR',0,'C',$fill);
    $this->Cell($w[5],6,$row[5],'LR',0,'C',$fill);



    $this->Ln();

    // flips from true to false and vise versa

    $fill =! $fill;

    }

    $this->Cell(array_sum($w),0,'','T');

    }

}

$sql = "";
$result = "";
$plate = "";
if($_POST)
{
    $vn = $g->clean($_POST["name"]);
    $d1 = $g->clean($_POST["d1"]);
    $d2 = $g->clean($_POST["d2"]);
    $plate = $vn;
if($vn == "" && $d1 == "" && $d2 == "")
{
    $sql = "SELECT vehiclelog_name, vehiclelog_plate, vehiclelog_date, vehiclelog_reftype, vehiclelog_refid, vehiclelog_description FROM vehiclelogs";

    $result = mysqli_query($g->connection(), $sql)

    or die( "Could not execute sql: $sql");
}

else if(!$vn == "" && $d1 == "" && $d2 == "")
{
    $sql = "SELECT vehiclelog_name, vehiclelog_plate, vehiclelog_date, vehiclelog_reftype, vehiclelog_refid, vehiclelog_description FROM vehiclelogs
    WHERE vehiclelog_plate='$vn'";

    $result = mysqli_query($g->connection(), $sql)

    or die( "Could not execute sql: $sql");
}

else if($vn == "" && !$d1 == "" && !$d2 == "")
{
    $da1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($d1));
    $da2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($d2));
    $sql = "SELECT vehiclelog_name, vehiclelog_plate, vehiclelog_date, vehiclelog_reftype, vehiclelog_refid, vehiclelog_description FROM vehiclelogs
    WHERE vehiclelog_date BETWEEN '$da1' AND '$da2'";

    $result = mysqli_query($g->connection(), $sql)

    or die( "Could not execute sql: $sql");
}

else if (!$vn == "" && !$d1 == "" && !$d2 == "")
{
    $da1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($d1));
    $da2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($d2));
    $sql = "SELECT vehiclelog_name, vehiclelog_plate, vehiclelog_date, vehiclelog_reftype, vehiclelog_refid, vehiclelog_description FROM vehiclelogs
    WHERE vehiclelog_date BETWEEN '$da1' AND '$da2' AND vehiclelog_plate='$vn'";

    $result = mysqli_query($g->connection(), $sql)

    or die( "Could not execute sql: $sql");
}
}

$getInfo = mysqli_query($g->connection(), "SELECT vehiclelog_name, vehiclelog_plate FROM vehiclelogs WHERE vehiclelog_plate='$vn'");

   // build the data array from the database records.

  While($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $data[] = array($row['vehiclelog_name'], $row['vehiclelog_plate'],      $row['vehiclelog_date'], $row['vehiclelog_reftype'],
    $row['vehiclelog_refid'], $row['vehiclelog_description']);

    }
    $plateNo = "";
    $model = "";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getInfo))
   {
  $plateNo = $row['vehiclelog_plate'];
  $model = $row['vehiclelog_name'];
   }

    // start and build the PDF document

    $pdf = new PDF();



    //Column titles

    $header=array('Model','Plate', 'Date', 'Reference Type', 'Reference ID', 'Description');



      $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',14);

      $pdf->AddPage('L', 'Legal');
      $pdf->SetXY(20,20);
      $pdf->image('../images/DCWD Watermark.png');
      $pdf->SetY(35);
      // call the table creation method
      $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
      $pdf->Cell(0,10,$plateNo);
      $pdf->SetY(45);
      $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
      $pdf->Cell(0,10,$model);
      $pdf->SetXY(310, 45);
      $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
      $pdf->Cell(0,10,date("m/d/Y"));
      $pdf->SetY(55);
      $pdf->BuildTable($header,$data);

      $pdf->Output();
   ?>
```

Above is the PHP being called after clicking **PRINT** button i created data is sent from my input fields through **AJAX** to be queried and printed as **PDF**.

How can I force open this PDF file i made with **FPDF** ? Everytime i click my PRINT button it just downloads with **IDM** but when i turn off **IDM's** browser integration nothing happens when i click print.

Answer (score 0):

Change your last line to:

```
$pdf->Output('', 'I');
```

The first parameter is the name you want to give to the file and the second is how the file is served.

'I' will send the pdf inline to the browser.

The other options are the following

```
I: send the file inline to the browser (default). The plug-in is used if available. The name given by name is used when one selects the "Save as" option on the link generating the PDF.
D: send to the browser and force a file download with the name given by name.
F: save to a local server file with the name given by name.
S: return the document as a string (name is ignored).
FI: equivalent to F + I option
FD: equivalent to F + D option
E: return the document as base64 mime multi-part email attachment (RFC 2045)
```

Comment: Do i still need to download a plugin for my browser? Coz this solution did not wor for me.

Comment: No, you don't need add any plugin to your browser, I mean, the needed plugin to view pdf files is already built-in in most browsers

Comment: Do i still need headers?